# getting instance as argument python

Tags: python, class, arguments

I want to get class instance into function as argument, like code below. I know it doesn`t work.

```
class coordinate:
  x = 1
  y = 2

inst = coordinate()

def get_class(instance):
  return instance.x + instance.y

get_class(inst)
```

Just getting instance`s inner variable is one of the solution, but the class that I want to use contains pretty diverse things. It makes code confusing

```
x = inst.x
y = inst.y

def get_class(x, y):
  return x + y

get_class(x, y)
```

Is there any possible way?

Comment: Deleting a question once you have received an answer is an abuse of this platform, please refrain from doing that again.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me point out that you probably want your `x` and `y` to be instance attributes and not class attributes.

Then if you want a function that takes a class instance as argument, what you want is probably an instance method.

```
class Coordinates:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def sum_coordinates(self):
        return self.x + self.y

Coordinates(1, 2).sum_coordinates() # 3
```